# How to get a div centered with another div on the right of it?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a centered `div` with another `div` on the right of it. So the `div` on the left is horizontal centered. De `div` on the right is directly on the right of the centered `div`. I've tried it in many ways with different displays and margins etc but I can't seem to figure it out.

All tips are welcome!

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#left {
  left: 50%;
  background: #009a9a;
}

#right {
  background: #bbad4f;
}
```

```html
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with the ***Flexbox*** and *positioning*:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex; /* displays flex-items (children) inline */
  justify-content: center; /* centers them horizontally */
  position: relative;
}

.flex-container > div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#left {
  background: #009a9a;
}

#right {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%; /* moved right by half of the parent's width */
  transform: translateX(50%); /* and half of its own width */
  background: #bbad4f;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

No matter the *divs width* (as long as they stay the same), this solution is *dynamic*, therefore no unnecessary *margins* or *calc()*.

But with the help of ***CSS variables*** you can make it completely *dynamic*:

```css
:root {
  --leftWidth: 200px;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.flex-container > div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#left {
  width: var(--leftWidth);
  background: #009a9a;
}

#right {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% + (var(--leftWidth)/2)); /* moved right by half of the parent's and sibling's width */
  background: #bbad4f;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#left {
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  position: relative;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #009a9a;
}

#right {
  background: #bbad4f;
  left: calc(50% + 100px);
  top: calc(50% + 100px);
  position: relative;
  transform: translate(calc(-50% - 100px), calc(-50% - 100px));
}
```

```html
<div id="left"></div>

<div id="right"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here another example if you can't use transform or if you don't know elements size. You can do it with flexbox or just just by using `margin: auto` to center the first element.

```css
.Container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.Left {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

.Centered {
  background-color: cyan;
  position: relative;
}

/* Demo only */

.Centered, .Left {
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 8px 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container"> 
  <div class="Centered">
    <div class="Left">Right</div>
    Centered
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

This is using absolute positions. Please not that the amount of `left:150px;` is the half width of centered div + half width of left div.  Also the style `margin-left:200px`; on the lef div, comes from the width of centered div.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.centered {
  width: 200px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.leftOf {
  background: #ff8800;
  position: absolute;
  left: 150px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="centered"></div>
  <div class="leftOf"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought the @J.Swinkels wanted only the orange one in center and the grey one on right of it !

Comment: @NanditaAroraSharma I thought the same. Text description is like that.

Comment: @J.Swinkels No offence but you should be clearer in asking what you want. :) Else it creates confusion and attracts wrong answers ! :(

Comment: You are right. I have updated the code after it was accepted . I just edited it to the accepted one. @NanditaAroraSharma

Comment: @NanditaAroraSharma Sorry! I'll try to be clearer next time, VXp nailed it with it answer tho. Thank you for your help anyways!

Comment: Hey no need to say sorry :) Was just advising you for future :)

Comment: How is this the accepted awnser? Both divs are on top of each other.

Comment: @ThomasScheffer Before his edit it was working like I wished, accepted answer changed.