# How to center inner div?

Tags: css

I have two divs:

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='left'></div>
  <div class='center'></div>
</div>
```

I want to center the second div ("center"),

and place the first inner div to the left of the center one.
im tring for hours with chrome and it don't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50852584/how-to-get-a-div-centered-with-another-div-on-the-right-of-it/50852962#50852962 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52221686/two-divs-alongside-each-other-first-sticked-and-the-second-centered#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this one

```css
.A {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.B {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

.C {
  background-color: cyan;
  position: relative;
}

.C,
.B {
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 8px 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="A">
  <div class="C">
    <div class="B">left text</div>
    center text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You changed the HTML structure.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.left {
  float :left;
  width: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  background: green;
}

.center {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="left">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="center">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think OP wants to have the green div stick to the red one - independent of resolution of course.

Comment: Solveable by adding the correct margin then

Comment: And what if you don't know the width of `.center`? It might have `width: min-content;`.

Comment: Then one should resort to `flex` and `justify-content` I guess

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution without flexbox:

```css
.main {
  text-align: center;
}

.main__inner {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.left {
  border: 1px solid tomato;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
}

.center {
  border: 1px solid cyan;
}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
  <div class='main__inner'>
    <div class='left'>left</div>
    <div class='center'>center</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

here is what I came up with:

```css
.main>* {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
  <div class='left'>abc</div>
  <div class='center'>def</div>
</div>
```

As demonstrated [here](http://www.cssdesk.com/w8Frj).

## Yet another solution

This solution will always place `.left` first.

HTML

```
<div class='main'>
  <div class='center'>def</div>
  <div class='left'>abc</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
}
.main > .left {
  order: 1;
}
.main > .center {
  order: 2;
}
```

And if you want your inner-boxes to have same width:

```
.main > * {
  flex-basis: 33%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To position the left element as far to the left as possible, you can work with the margin of the center element, as demonstrated below.

Border and background colors are for visibility purpose and not necessary.

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  border: thin solid black;
}

.left {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
}

.center {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
  <div class='left'>Left</div>
  <div class='center'>Center</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```css
.center{max-width:300px; margin:0 auto; overflow:hidden;}
.center .innerDiv {float:left; width:50%;}
```

```html
<div class="center">
<div class="innerDiv"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you even tried to run your own code here?